# How to get entire json body as user-input and store in a variable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, user-input

I would like to get the below json body as a user input to store in a variable and pass it across.It is in multi-line inputs

```
     {
     "key1": "value1",
     "key2": "value2",
     "key3": "value3",
     "key4": "value4",
     "key5": "value5",
     "key6": "value6",
     "key7": "value7",
     "key8": "value8"
     }
```

I have tried below,

```
import json
allow = json.dumps(input("Enter your Json body: "))
print(allow)
print(json.loads(allow))

variable = {
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2",
 "key3": "value3",
 "key4": "value4",
 "key5": "value5",
 "key6": "value6",
 "key7": "value7",
 "key8": "value8"
 }
```

I need to pass the variable in multiple line to an function as a same JSON body.

Comment: `variable = json.loads(allow)`.

Comment: Hi, i am tried to get the json body as a multi line input, but i am not able to get the multi line user input

Comment: Adding an comment - This is a multi-line input.

Comment: Do you want to get a multi-line user input through `stdin`? Or, it is very simple. You can do `v = json.loads(json_str)` or `v = json.load(open(json_file))`.

Comment: it should be like json_str = input("Enter the json body"). Then user enters {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5",
    "key6": "value6" But in this is just taking the first line as input, it is not considering further lines. were i need to capture the whole content into the string and then display as such..